# Record video in background with mencoder

Tags: linux, mplayer, mencoder

I have an USB tv stick Sundtek MediaTV Pro III which has an analog input.
with the following command, recording works perfectly.

```
mencoder tv:// -tv driver=v4l2:width=720:height=576:outfmt=uyvy:device=/dev/video0:input=1:fps=25:adevice=/dev/dsp0:audiorate=48000:amode=1:forceaudio:immediatemode=0 -ffourcc DX50 -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:mbd=2:turbo:vbitrate=1200:keyint=15 -oac mp3lame -noskip -o video1.avi
```

The only problem I have is, that I can hear the sound while recording.

This is kind of annoying because I want to be able to watch a move (a file, not with the usb stick), while I am recoding the analog tv stream.

How can I record without hearing the sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
/opt/bin/mediaclient -c external -d /dev/video0
```

this is telling the driver not to play back audio via the speaker

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So is it correct to assume that the sundtek driver himself is streaming the audio to the speakers and not mencoder? If I apply this command, will watching with tvtime or mplayer still work or do I have to swich it back to internal or auto ?

Comment: /opt/bin/mediaclient -c internal -d /dev/video0

will switch back to the old behaviour.
This is all derived from the old days where TV tuners where wired up manually with the soundcard.
The applications back then only told the device to enable audio on the device. Audio was passed via an additional analog cable to the soundcard (line-in) and directly output via the main audio output.
No software logic for handling the audio data itself was required back then.
The driver is only simulating this old behavior.